# How can I convert a randomly generated array of binary numbers to decimals in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am making a small program in python that allows me to convert from binary to decimal, I ask you:

The code asks the user for the number of binaries to generate and the quantity that the binary number must contain, this combination is carried out at random.
Once I have the matrix with the numbers in binary, I must convert each number generated to decimal. At the time of conversion, I get the following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 32, in 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: ' '**

my code is the following:

```
import json 
import random

binarios = input('Enter the number of binaries to generate:')
binarios=int(binarios)
digitos = input('Write the number of digits to use:')
digitos=int(digitos)

matriz = [[0 for x in range(digitos)] for x in range(binarios)]

for i in range(binarios):
   for j in range(digitos):
      matriz[i][j] = random.randint(0, 1) 
    
print (matriz)

lista = matriz
cadena = json.dumps(lista)
newstring = cadena.replace("[","")
new1 = newstring.replace("]]","]")
new2 = new1.replace("]","\n")
new3 = new2.replace(",","")
new4 = new3.replace(" ","")
new5 = new4.replace("\n"," ")

numerofinal = int(new5, 2)
print(numerofinal)
```

Comment: Hola! Probablemente deberías o traducir a inglés este mensaje, o ponerlo en https://es.stackoverflow.com/, que es stack overflow en castellano.

Hi! Probably you should translate this message to english or send it to es.stackoverflow.com, which is SO spanish version

Comment: Ya esta traducido.